# How can I retrieve the JSON Object Array Value using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, json

My JSON Object Array is something like this:

```
var country = [{ id: "1", name:"ajith",   country:"india"},
               { id: "2", name:"chandru", country:"india"}, 
               { id: "3", name:"gane",    country:"india"}]
```

How can I retrieve these key and values?
And how can I display them in an html table?

Answer (score 3):

Like so, just replace `<tableIdHere>` with your table's id

```
document.getElementById('<tableIdHere>').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].innerHTML = 
country.map(v => `<tr><td>${v.id}</td><td>${v.name}</td><td>${v.country}</td></tr>`)
    .join('');
```

Please note that [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings) as used above are only available in modern browsers like latest chrome and firefox. You might want to use

```
document.getElementById('<tableIdHere>').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].innerHTML = 
country.map(function(v) {
    return  '<tr><td>' + v.id + '</td><td>' + v.name + '</td><td>' + v.country + '</td></tr>';
}).join('');
```

if you need support for older browsers!

Comment: Side comment, that's an elegant way of using `$.map`